# Help with Twitter Advanced Search: Retrieve Tweets, Replies, Quotes, and Retweets within a Date Range form user

Tags: twitter, twitter-api, twitter-search

I'm trying to see some tweets from a specific Twitter user within a specified date range using Twitter Advanced Search. Currently, I've been using the following queries:

1. To get Tweets, Replies, and Quotes:

   ```
   (from:user) since:2023-01-01 until:2024-01-01
   ```
2. To get only Retweets:

   ```
    (from:user) since:2023-01-01 +filter:nativeretweets
   ```

However, I'm facing a limitation when trying to get Retweets within a specific date range. If I add an "until" parameter to the second query, I receive no results.

Is there a way to retrieve all Tweets, Replies, Quotes, and Retweets from a user within a particular date range using Twitter Advanced Search? Or, is there a workaround to add an "until" parameter and get Retweets within a date range?